# Gradle where to get tomcat server from repository

Tags: gradle, tomcat8

Is tomcat server(zip, about 8M) available in a public repository? It would be nice for gradle to download and install it.

Comment: I'm not sure of your requirements (e.g. install it outside of Gradle?), but the Gretty plugin runs web-apps within embedded servlet containers including Tomcat - https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty

Comment: yes, distribution includes tomcat.zip